# element() vs. node() in XQuery

Tags: xquery, exist-db

Can someone tell me the exact difference between `node()` and `element()` types in XQuery? The documentation states that `element()` is an element node, while `node()` is any node, so if I understand it correctly `element()` is a subset of `node()`.

The thing is I have an XQuery function like this:

```
declare function local:myFunction($arg1 as element()) as element() {
    let $value := data($arg1/subelement)
   etc...
};
```

Now I want to call the function with a parameter which is obtained by another function, say `functionX` (which I have no control over):

```
let $parameter := someNamespace:functionX()
return local:myFunction($parameter)
```

The problem is, `functionX` returns an `node()` so it will not let me pass the `$parameter` directly. I tried changing the type of my function to take a `node()` instead of an `element()`, but then I can’t seem to read any data from it. `$value` is just empty.

Is there some way of either converting the node to an element or should am I just missing something?

**EDIT:** As far as I can tell the problem is in the part where I try to get the subelement using `$arg1/subelement`. Apparently you can do this if `$arg1` is an `element()` but not if it is a `node()`.

**UPDATE:** I have tested the example provided by Dimitre below, and it indeed works fine, both with Saxon and with eXist DB (which is what I am using as the XQuery engine). The problem actually occurs with the `request:get-data()` function from eXist DB. This function gets data provided by the POST request when using eXist through REST, parses it as XML and returns it as a `node()`. But for some reason when I pass the data to another function XQuery doesn’t acknowledge it as being a valid `element()`, even though it is. If I extract it manually (i.e. copy the output and paste it to my source code), assign it to a variable and pass it to my function all goes well. But if I pass it directly it gives me a runtime error (and indeed fails the `instance of` test).

I need to be able to either make it ignore this type-check or “typecast” the data to an `element()`.

Comment: @_NobleK: Did you read my answer and was it useful?

Comment: Hello Dimitre. I have read it, but I have not yet had a chance to test it, since I am at work. I will look at it later this evening and I will let you know what my findings are.

Comment: @NobleK, I updated my answer based on the new information you provided. I believe we've solved our mystery. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data()` returning empty for an element just because the argument type is `node()` sounds like a bug to me. What XQuery processor are you using?

It sounds like you need to placate static type checking, which you can do using a `treat as` expression. I don't believe a dynamic test using `instance of` will suffice.

Try this:

```
let $parameter := someNamespace:functionX() treat as element()
return local:myFunction($parameter)
```

Quoting from the 4th edition of Michael Kay's magnum opus, "The `treat as` operator is essentially telling the system that you know what the runtime type is going to be, and you want any checking to be deferred until runtime, because you're confident that your code is correct." (p. 679)

**UPDATE:** I think the above is actually wrong, since `treat as` is just an assertion. It doesn't change the type annotation `node()`, which means it's also a wrong assertion and doesn't help you. Hmmm... What I really want is `cast as`, but that only works for atomic types. I guess I'm stumped. Maybe you should change XQuery engines. :-) I'll report back if I think of something else. Also, I'm curious to find out if Dimitre's solution works for you.

**UPDATE #2:** I had backpedaled here earlier. Can I backpedal again? ;-) Now my theory is that `treat as` *will* work based on the fact that `node()` is interpreted as a union of the various specific node type annotations, and not as a run-time type annotation itself (see the "Note" in the ["Item types" section of the XQuery formal semantics](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-semantics/#sec_item_types).) At run time, the type annotation will be `element()`. Use `treat as` to guarantee to the type checker that this will be true. Now I wait on bated breath: does it work for you?

**EXPLANATORY ADDENDUM:** Assuming this works, here's why. `node()` is a union type. Actual items at run time are never annotated with `node()`. "An item type is either an atomic type, an element type, an attribute type, a document node type, a text node type, a comment node type, or a processing instruction type."[1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-semantics/#sec_item_types) Notice that `node()` is not in that list. Thus, your XQuery engine isn't complaining that an item has type `node()`; rather it's complaining that it doesn't *know* what the type is going to be (`node()` means it could end up being `attribute()`, `element()`, `text()`, `comment()`, `processing-instruction()`, or `document-node()`). Why does it have to know? Because you're telling it elsewhere that it's an element (in your function's signature). It's not enough to narrow it down to one of the above six possibilities. Static type checking means that you have to guarantee—at compile time—that the types will match up (element with element, in this case). `treat as` is used to narrow down the static type from a general type (`node()`) to a more specific type (`element()`). It doesn't change the dynamic type. `cast as`, on the other hand, is used to convert an item from one type to another, changing both the static and dynamic types (e.g., xs:string to xs:boolean). It makes sense that `cast as` can only be used with atomic values (and not nodes), because what would it mean to convert an attribute to an element (etc.)? And there's no such thing as converting a `node()` item to an `element()` item, because there's no such thing as a `node()` item. `node()` only exists as a static union type. Moral of the story? Avoid XQuery processors that use static type checking. (Sorry for the snarky conclusion; I feel I've earned the right. :-) )

**NEW ANSWER BASED ON UPDATED INFORMATION**: It sounds like static type checking is a red herring (a big fat one). I believe you are in fact *not* dealing with an element but a **document node**, which is the invisible root node that contains the top-level element (document element) in the XPath data model representation of a well-formed XML document.

The tree is thus modeled like this:

```
      [document-node]
             |
        <docElement>
             |
        <subelement>
```

and *not* like this:

```
        <docElement>
             |
        <subelement>
```

I had assumed you were passing the `<docElement>` node. But if I'm right, you were actually passing the document node (its parent). Since the document node is invisible, its serialization (what you copied and pasted) is indistinguishable from an element node, and the distinction was lost when you pasted what is now interpreted as a bare element constructor in your XQuery. (To construct a document node in XQuery, you have to wrap the element constructor with `document{ ... }`.)

The `instance of` test fails because the node is *not* an element but a document-node. (It's not a `node()` per se, because there's no such thing; see explanation above.)

Also, this would explain why `data()` returns empty when you tried to get the `<subelement>` child of the document node (after relaxing the function argument type to `node()`). The first tree representation above shows that `<subelement>` is *not* a child of the document node; thus it returns the empty sequence.

Now for the solution. Before passing the (document node) parameter, get its element child (the document element), by appending `/*` (or `/element()` which is equivalent) like this:

```
let $parameter := someNamespace:functionX()/*
return local:myFunction($parameter)
```

Alternatively, let your function take a document node and update the argument you pass to data():

```
declare function local:myFunction($arg1 as document-node()) as element() {
    let $value := data($arg1/*/subelement)
   etc...
};
```

Finally, it looks like the [description of eXist's request:get-data() function](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/functions/request/get-data) is perfectly consistent with this explanation. It says: "If its not a binary document, we attempt to parse it as XML *and return a document-node()*." (emphasis added)

Thanks for the adventure. This turned out to be a common XPath gotcha (awareness of document nodes), but I learned a few things from our detour into static type checking.

Comment: Evan, Why do you doubt "if Dimitre's solution works" ? Just run it with Saxon, as I do always before posting code.

Comment: I meant if it works using the OP's XQuery engine, which appears to be using static type checking. If that's the case, then I don't think `instance of` will prevent the error message they're seeing.

Comment: Evan, the OP says in his question that with his his code "*you can do this if $arg1 is an element()*" . This statement means that he gets only a runtime error -- in the cases when `$arg1` isn't an element.

Comment: My interpretation was that he was getting an error despite passing in an element, i.e. an error that occurs unless $arg1 is known statically to be an element. I guess we'll both have to wait and see. :-)

Comment: Hi guys. Just to clarify the issue, the value I am passing to `$arg1` does contain XML which by any definition should be a valid `element()`.I suspect that it has something to do with how the `request:get-data()` function (se the update above) passes the XML, even though it should just be an `node()`. So in this case `instance of` does not solve the problem since it too becomes a victim of the “false” type-check. I am hoping that `treat as` will be the medicine I need, but I cannot test it until I come home later today.

Comment: Wow, Evan, thank you for a really great job, sincerely. I believe that this is the most elaborate answer I have ever got on SO, which not only solved my problem but really made it clear to me what was causing it in the first place. And yes, you were right on the money – the `/*` did the job. I had actually read the documentation for `request:get-data()` but I missed the dash between “document” and “node” and read the return type to be a `node()` which then caused all the confusion for me :)

Answer (score 2):

**This works perfectly using Saxon 9.3**:

```
declare namespace my = "my:my";
declare namespace their = "their:their";

declare function my:fun($arg1 as element()) as element() 
{
            $arg1/a
};

declare function their:fun2($arg1 as node()) as node() 
{
            $arg1
};

my:fun(their:fun2(/*) )
```

**when the code above is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
  <a/>
</t>
```

**the correct result is produced with no error messages**:

```
<a/>
```

**Update**:

The following should work even with the most punctuential static type-checking XQuery implementation:

```
declare namespace my = "my:my";
declare namespace their = "their:their";

declare function my:fun($arg1 as element()) as element() 
{
            $arg1/a
};

declare function their:fun2($arg1 as node()) as node() 
{
            $arg1
};

 let $vRes :=  their:fun2(/*) 
  (: this prevents our code from runtime crash :)
  return if($vRes instance of  element())
     then
       (: and this assures the static type-checker 
          that the type is element() :)
       my:fun(their:fun2(/*) treat as element())
     else()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Dimitre. I have tested your code and it indeed does work. I suspected that the issue might be with the fact that I am using eXist DB as the xquery engine. However your example worked with eXist as well.

Comment: @NobleK: You are welcome. I have asked myself the *theoretical* question if a static type-checking processor is useful, but never have had the experience of using one. Now, seeing this practical example, I am starting to believe that all the hassle may indeed be worth it, because without the static error there could be cases of an XQuery app that seems to operate "normally" for some time and then suddenly starts producing runtime errors. If the application is of important nature (such as e-commerce), we, naturally don't want any unpredictable runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

`node()` is an element, attribute, processing instruction, text node, etc.

But `data()` converts the result to a string, which isn't any of those; it's a primitive type.

You might want to try `item()`, which should match either.

See [2.5.4.2 Matching an ItemType and an Item](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-matching-item) in the W3C XQuery spec.

Although it's not shown in your example code, I assume you are actually returning a value (like the `$value` you are working with) from the `local:myFunction`.

Comment: Hi lavinio. Thank you for the reply. However, I think there might be a misunderstanding. The problem is not in the return type of my function but in the type of the argument $arg1. For me to be able to pass the node returned by functionX, the type of $arg1 must be node(). But then I cannot read its data, which I am able to read just fine if the type is element().

Comment: Quick correction: `data()` returns a sequence of zero or more atomic values, not necessarily a string. If there's no schema, then the result is like a string but annotated as xs:untypedAtomic.